# Isn't Combination just selection?

Tags: combinations

So,
There is this question which I came across.
"Total no of handshakes among 15 people."
 The answer seems to be just <sub>15</sub>C<sub>2</sub>.
Isn't that just a way of selecting and not the number of handshakes?
I'm in grade 10th. So don't judge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mean, $_{15}C_2$ gives a numerical result as well even if describes a method of selection:

$$_{15}C_2 = \frac{15!}{2! \cdot (15-2)!}$$

and generally

$$_{n}C_r = \frac{n!}{r! \cdot (n-r)!}$$

Do the calculations and boom, a number. $_{n}C_r$ is just a notation representing the underlying number (or, rather, the calculations leading up to that number), because who wants to write that fraction *every single time*?

Comment: I'm not quite sure. 15C2 in literal terms means, you select 2 objects out of 15. Nowhere does it say that selection is equal to the number of handshakes. Pardon if i'm missing something obvious.

Comment: What are you unsure about?

Comment: Check it out. I edited it.

Comment: No, $_{15}C_2$ represents the *number of ways* in which you can choose $2$ objects from $15$. It does not mean "choose a single pair of $2$ from $15$" - it means the number of ways in whichiyou can choose those pairs. I guess, yes, you could argue that in the sense of languages and the usual connotation in English it means to choose $2$ from $15$, but if you go on to study math one day in more depth you'll realize that the mathematical meaning and the common/everyday meaning may differ greatly.

Comment: Mathematicians make very poor poets, so to speak, and can suck at developing intuitive, not-confusing notations/conventions for various things. But either way, that's just how mathematical notation and standards have developed.

Comment: I get it now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$_{15}C_2$ is the number of ways to select 2 people from 15 people (when order doesn't matter). This is exactly the number of handshakes that occur if $15$ people all shake hands with each other. There is one handshake for each set of 2 people.